# Ubuntu 16.04 very slow at startup

Tags: 16.04, startup

Ubuntu started to be very slow in the startup and when it shuts down
i have included my bootchart image so you can help me figure out what makes the delay and how to fix it
[image: ubuntu.png]

Comment: I can't see the text in your image.

Comment: fixed now hope you can help

Comment: It would help if you add your specs.

Comment: @Inforcer25 what do you mean by "your specs" ?